# Interesting transformation of English letters

Tags: knowledge, letters

English letters are transformed like so:

*B → V*

*C → S*

*E → E*

*H → N*

*T → T*

Now what does *P* transform to and why?

Comment: That sound doesn't exist in native English words; any word that has that sound in it is borrowed, and the spelling may vary from word to word.

Comment: oooh I feel that you worked it out. Let me fix the question, so it has a good answer.

Comment: You gave the answer to the fix in the previous version. Anyone can get the answer by looking at the edit history. I believe that I did work it out; if I did, then 3 transforms to Z.;

Comment: @JeffZeitlin yep you did work it out! 3 is a good example I forgot about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be

> R

Because

> the l.h.s. "English" letters are in fact Cyrillic letters posing as Latin.

Comment: When the puzzle _explicitly says_ "English letters", I feel there's something a bit https://xkcd.com/169/ about this.

Comment: (I don't mean to suggest that there's anything wrong with your answer. Obviously it's right, especially as it's got the green checkmark and all. It's the _puzzle_ that feels a bit XKCD 169 to me.)

Comment: Eugh, gratuitous violence. I suppose you could always chain the "find-closest-looking-Cyrillic" and the "find-closest-sounding-English" maps if it really bothers you.